# Google map issue with IE8

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8

I am using Google API v3 version for showing maps.

I have a page with 3 tabs. Showing Google maps in second tab. My issue is markers not visible in ie8. I checked the same in a page without tabs and google maps loading correctly for the same in IE8.

I am using the script,

```
$('.tabLocation').click(function (e) {
            var myMap = document.getElementById("mapPanel");

            var lastCenter = map.getCenter();
            var myMap = document.getElementById("mapPanel");
            google.maps.event.trigger(myMap, 'resize');
            map.setCenter(lastCenter)
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom());
});
```

Comment: can you please create jsfiddle of your current code?

Comment: where are you adding markers?

Answer (score 0):

Google map is not compatible with IE8 because IE8 does not support HTML5 technology.

Many large technology companies, such as Google, have stopped supporting older browsers (IE8 included) in order to focus on advancing the future of internet technology (like 'HTML5').

Perhaps most notable is that Microsoft has been forcing IE updates from IE8 to IE9 through windows updates (although you can opt-out of this) - for the same reasons stated above. You can read more in the Windows blog post from last year here.

Unfortunately we will not be able to provide support for IE8 and other older browsers that do not support HTML5.

You can also read the article on the Wix Blog [here](http://www.wix.com/blog/2012/05/wix-html5-product-drops-support-for-ie8/).

Comment: From where you copy pasted this stuff is actually says `**Wix** is not compatible with IE8 because IE8 does not support HTML5 technology.`

Comment: same case here ... wix is a web site creation platform

Comment: **`Google map is compatible with IE8`**

Comment: Read the 3rd point from above link which you have given. `Microsoft Internet Explorer version 8 and later.`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I tried loading map in IE8 inside a sample page without tabs and is working fine.

Hope the issue is with the tabs.

Please clarify the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is wrong :

```
google.maps.event.trigger(myMap, 'resize');
```

Google map trigger require a map object but **myMap** is not a map object , it's a html element .

Here the prototype of google map trigger :

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map-object, 'event-name');
```

map-object is created by this code :

```
new google.maps.Map(element-container, options);
```

element-container can get by this code :

```
document.getElementById('id');
```

I think your code should change like this :

```
$('.tabLocation').click(function (e)
{
    var lastCenter = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(lastCenter)
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom());
});
```